# What is the meaning of the optional asterisk following the table name in the Redshift SELECT documentation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In the AWS Redshift [FROM clause documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FROM_clause30.html) there is an asterisk symbol shown as optional following the table_name literal. Anyone know to what that is referring or means? The context in that page does not mention it.

I am wondering about the `[ * ]` bit highlighted in the image below:

[image: AWS Redshift FROM clause syntax]

I tried a couple variations of the following that gave the same error but maybe I am not using it in a meaningful way. Looking up the error message did not return anything interesting.

```
my_db=# select count(*) from my_table * t;
ERROR:  "relation*" is not supported
```

Comment: A good question! I've submitted a Feedback request on that page to find out. Is there anything you were trying to achieve with this, or were you just curious?

Comment: Seems like there are regular questions on SO looking to do more dynamic queries on Redshift. So I was looking for any feature in the FROM specification that could be leveraged to, for example, accept the output of another query as the table name.

Comment: I'm not aware of the ability to pass the output of one command to another command. You'd have to do it in the calling program.

Comment: Yep. I was looking at PREPARE/EXECUTE, but the values passed into the constructed query are interpreted as character literals when I was hoping for column references. The documentation for QUOTE_IDENT is a tease saying a string "can be used as an identifier in a SQL statement", but they mean by an external process that is constructing a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is copied from the [PostgreSQL syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-select.html) and relates to including/excluding inherited tables.

However, Amazon Redshift [does not support inheritance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html), so I'd say that this is a documentation error.

The error output is:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: "relation*" is not supported;
```

I shall lodge some feedback against the documentation.